# How to mock functions from base?

Tags: r, mocking, testthat

I am calling a function from base in my code and I want to mock this function in my `testthat` unit test.

How can I do this?

```
library(testthat)

my.func <- function() {
  return(Sys.info()["sysname"])   # e. g. "Linux"
}

my.func()
# sysname 
# "Linux" 

test_that("base function can be mocked",
  with_mock(
    Sys.info = function() return(list(sysname = "Clever OS")),  # see edit 2 !!!
    expect_equal(my.func(), "Clever OS", fixed = TRUE)
  )
)
# Error: Test failed: 'base function can be mocked'
# * my.func() not equal to "Clever OS".
```

`?with_mock` says:

> Functions in base packages cannot be mocked, but this can be worked
>   around easily by defining a wrapper function.

I could encapsulate the base function call to `Sys.info()` by a wrapper function that I call from `my.func` then but let's assume I cannot do this because I am testing a function from a package that I cannot change...

Any solution for this?

I am using R3.4.4 64 Bit on Ubuntu 14.04 with testthat 2.0.0.9000.

**Edit 1:**

Using

```
`base::Sys.info` = function() return(list(sysname = "Clever OS"))
```

results in the `testthat` error msg:

> Can't mock functions in base packages (base)

**Edit 2:** As @suren show in his answer my code example here is wrong (the mocked function returns another class then the original one :-(

The correct mock function should be: `Sys.info = function() return(c(sysname = "Clever OS"))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is *my.func() not equal to "Clever OS".*. 
The reason is that `Sys.info` returns a named character vector while your mocking function a `list`.

Just modify the mocking function and the expected value and it works:

```
test_that("base function can be mocked",
  with_mock(
    Sys.info = function() return(c(sysname = "Clever OS")),
    expect_equal(my.func(), c(sysname = "Clever OS"), fixed = TRUE)
  )
)
```

This works even within a package.

**Note: Mocking of base functions shouldn't work according to the help of `with_mock` but it does (at the moment at least).**

The following (my.func()$`sysname`) seems to pass the test with the original code from the question.

```
test_that("base function can be mocked",
          with_mock(
            Sys.info = function() return(list(sysname = "Clever OS")), 
            expect_equal(my.func()$`sysname`, "Clever OS", fixed = TRUE)
          )
)
```

Alternatively, have a list where the string in `expect_equal`

```
test_that("base function can be mocked",
          with_mock(
            Sys.info = function() return(list(sysname = "Clever OS")),  
            expect_equal(my.func(), list(`sysname` = "Clever OS"), fixed = TRUE)
          )
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to work even within a package. Your answer is based on my defective example code were `Sys.info` returns a character vector while my mock function returns a list so you have fixed my problem + it works now even to mock base functions. Either the help for `with_mock` is outdated or something else has changed. I will **not** update my wrong code example for consistency, please update your answer to correct my mock with `Sys.info = function() return(c(sysname = "Clever OS"))`.

Comment: I have published a github repo to evaluate the problem within a package (mocking a base function within a package works! - even though the help for `with_mock` says it does not work):  https://github.com/aryoda/testthat_base_mocking

Comment: @RYoda Glad, it helped. Why don't you edit my answer? If not, I will do so later.

Comment: @Surren Edit done, please verify and adjust as you want

Answer (score 3):

**Warning about mocking base functions using `with_mock`:**

Even though mocking of base functions may work in case of my question and the accepted answer of @Suren many issues around `with_mock` in the package `testthat` disencourage to mock base package functions (or even functions outside of the package under test), e. g.

[testthat 2.0.0 - Breaking API changes](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/blob/master/NEWS.md)

- "Can't mock functions in base packages": You can no longer use with_mock() to mock functions in base packages, because this no longer works in R-devel due to changes with the byte code compiler. **I recommend using `mockery` or `mockr` instead.**

[Don't allow base packages to be mocked](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/pull/553)

[with_mock() function seems to interact badly with the JIT compiler](https://github.com/sainathadapa/stubthat/issues/7)

- As I mentioned in hadley/testthat#546 (comment), **mockery already has a replacement function for with_mock called stub, which takes a different approach to mocking things out that is not restricted** by the issues raised in the other threads. If with_mock breaks, I think this package would work just as well with mockery. I also think mockery would be a reasonable place to house with_mock, where it could live alongside stub for legacy reasons.

[Prevent with_mock from touching base R packages](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues/546)